# WIn32API - Subclassing a window, my first attempt

Tags: c, winapi

I've been trying to create a child window by subclassing the parent window procedure. I've encountered some really weird behavior that I cannot figure out.

After the `CreateWindow()` call is made, the code stops executing and immediately jumps to the top of the code-block (which is a `WM_CREATE` message) and executes everything over again in an infinite loop.

I've never done this before, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code.

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK EditorProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    RECT rect; 
    HWND RichEdit;
    HWND Toolbar;
    HWND ListboxType, ListboxArch;
    HWND hwndBuildButton;
    HWND Labels;

    hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        LoadLibrary(TEXT ("Msftedit.dll"));
    
        //Create Child Windows

        RichEdit = CreateWindow(MSFTEDIT_CLASS, TEXT("EDITOR"), WS_CHILD | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
            0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd, RichEditorID, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
        
        Toolbar = CreateWindow(TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, WS_CHILD | TBSTYLE_FLAT, 0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd,
            ToolBarID, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
        
        ListboxType = CreateWindow(WC_LISTBOX, NULL, WS_CHILD| WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 0, 0, Toolbar, ChildID1 + 2,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
        
        ListboxArch = CreateWindow(WC_LISTBOX, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 0, 0, Toolbar, ChildID1 + 3,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
        
        hwndBuildButton = CreateWindow(WC_BUTTON, L"Build", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 0, 0, 0, 0, Toolbar, ChildID1 + 4,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

        Labels = CreateWindow(szEditorName,NULL, WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd, ChildID1 + 5,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
        
        OriginalProc = SetWindowLong(Labels, GWL_WNDPROC, LabelProc);

        EnumChildWindows(hwnd, EditorChildProc, (LPARAM)&rect);
        
        return 0;
```

Here's the subclass window procedure:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK LabelProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{   
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    TCHAR ArchLabel[] = (L"Architecture:");
    TCHAR BuildLabel[] = (L"Build Type:");
    hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        SetTextAlign(hdc, TA_TOP);
        TextOut(hdc, 50, 50, ArchLabel, ARRAYSIZE(ArchLabel));
        TextOut(hdc, 100, 50, BuildLabel, ARRAYSIZE(BuildLabel));
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return TRUE;
    }

    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    
    return CallWindowProcA(OriginalProc, hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The code stops and repeats at:

```cpp
Labels = CreateWindow(szEditorName,NULL, WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd, ChildID1 + 5,
    GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

Comment: Perfect example of error code. Where is szEditorName defined? Is custom class or not? Definition of ChildID1 and ToolBarID ? In LabelProc you obtaining hdc twice ( GetDC, BeginPaint). Why mixing TCHAR (in 2021...) and WCHAR types? You call ANSI version of the CallWindowProc, but you build as UNICODE.

Comment: It behaves like you called RegisterWindowEx() to register szEditorName, also with LabelProc as the window procedure.  So CallWindowProc() is going to call LabelProc again and that goes on over and over again until the program crashes with this site's name.  Subclassing is not appropriate when you create your own window class.  Consider to use a static control (WC_STATIC) to display a label.

Comment: I have created my own window class yes. I didn't catch the ChildWindowProcA.... That was a mistake. I will remove the GetDC call as you are right BeginPaint and EndPaint will take care of that. I was going to use a static control, but I read on MSDN static classes are only intended to be used with dialogs. Which, this is a window, not a dialog. Thank you both for your input. I'm still very new to the Win32 API and thus I don't exactly know what I'm doing yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: Everything in this answer is assumption, because we can not see all code.*

I hope in this line:

```
Labels = CreateWindow(szEditorName,NULL, WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd, ChildID1 + 5,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

**szEditorName** is not same class name as your parent window.
If yes, why you are surprised about infinite loop?

*You create parent szEditorName window, in WM_CREATE create child windows, but last
window have same class as the parent, so same window procedure, so EditorProc is called again and again and again......*

Comment: So, every single child window I create has to have it's own class? That makes sense now that I think about it. Thanks for the information. I'm still new to the win32 api, so I've got allot to learn.